# What does the + operator do in this R code?

Tags: r

I am learning Time Series Analysis in R and came across this code in [this](https://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-plots.html) ebook:

```
ggseasonplot(a10, year.labels=TRUE, year.labels.left=TRUE) +
  ylab("$ million") +
  ggtitle("Seasonal plot: antidiabetic drug sales")
```

From what I could find by googling, the + operator is supposed to continue a command to the next line but here it seems to be "adding" functions. Can anyone explain how this works and what exactly is happening?

Comment: You have to see it as a superposition of layers. This is the `ggplot` philosophy.Check the-grammar-of-graphics in google.

Comment: Some background from the author of ggplot2: https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-cant-ggplot2-use/4372/7

Comment: ...and the relevant help page: [Add components to a plot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/gg-add.html)